# Select table with subquery

Tags: php, mysql

i try to list out all products with product images, but not sure how to use `subquery` in this situation. Below is my database structure

products

```
products_id + product_name +
    1       |    Apple     |
    2       |    Banana    |
```

products_screenshot

```
products_id +       images       +
    1       |    Apple-1.jpg     |
    1       |    Apple-2.jpg     |
    1       |    Apple-3.jpg     |
    2       |    Banana-1.jpg    |
    2       |    Banana-2.jpg    |
    2       |    Banana-3.jpg    |
```

this is my query:

```
$sql = "SELECT p.* FROM `products` p ORDER BY p.products_id ASC ";

//LEFT JOIN (SELECT ps.* FROM `products_screenshot` ps WHERE ps.products_id=p.products_id) AS pss ON(p.products_id=pss.products_id)

$query = $db->query($sql);

while ($row = $query->fetch_object()) {

     // result
     echo $row->products_name.'</br>';

     // list all product screenshot related with this 
     //$row->images

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your requirement you can do as below. Then execute the query and loop through.
The 
$row->images will be comma seperated and you can split them display them for a product.

```
$sql = "SELECT p.products_id,p.product_name,group_concat(pi.images) as `images`
FROM `products` p 
left join products_screenshot  pi on pi.products_id = p.products_id
group by p.products_id
ORDER BY p.products_id ";
```

If you dont care about products being repeated multiple times in the loop then just use below where for each loop you will get a new row with the product and the related images

```
$sql = "SELECT p.products_id,p.product_name,pi.images
FROM `products` p 
left join products_screenshot  pi on pi.products_id = p.products_id
ORDER BY p.products_id ";
```

Comment: in the result, I'm split this string into an array using explode `$images_array = explode(',', $row->images);`

Answer (score 1):

What wrong with a simple query like this:

```
select
    p.products_id,
    p.product_name,
    ps.images
from
    products p
        join products_screenshot ps
            on p.products_id=ps.products_id
where
    whateveryouline
order by
    1,2
```

It will get you all the items you need?

Comment: It'll also get him a return of the products table for each line in the images table so yes for me i'd do it your way and detect on loop unique product ID for only spitting out headers / product name once etc he may be as well just doing a second query inside his primary while keep it simple while he learns.

Comment: @Dave I never find anything wrong with returning all the required data in a single query (well, almost never anyhow) and then simply sorting into a simple object which sorts things out as needed.

Comment: yeah there isn't but considering he's struggling with the basics :) more advanced stuff could be out of his reach

Comment: @Dave I have NEVER had a problem with learning new tricks. The logic is simple enough. The only caveat is to WANT to learn new tricks. I always hope to encourage that flame to burn.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select products.product_name, products_screenshot.images from products,products_screenshot  where products.products_id = products_screenshot.products_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from products_screenshot as ps where products_id IN (SELECT p.products_id from products as p WHERE p.products_id = ps.products_id )
```